# Extracting grouped objects into a flattened list

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to optimize this javascript method because it is a bit slow, I don't want to use the flat() command, as for some reason my angular6 app does not understand the vanilla flat() command, or display some annoying warning messages.

So check the below:

> 1. my original object
> 2. my result object desired
> 3. my slow solution (works, but is slow)

**1. my original object:**

```
  const data = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Application",
        "groups": [
          {
            "groupName": "",
            "configurations": [
              {
                "id": 17,
                "icon": "access_time",
                "title": "Daily Order Cut-Off Time",
                "description": "Daily Order Cut-Off Time",
                "code": "daily-order-cut-off-time",
                "value": "09:35",
                "valueType": "Time",
                "configurationTypeId": 11,
                "definition": {
                  "step": "none"
                },
                "isDefault": false
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Processing",
        "groups": [
          {
            "groupName": "",
            "configurations": [
              {
                "id": 1078,
                "icon": "flash_on",
                "title": "Auto Process",
                "description": "Will process all orders that are in the same batch",
                "code": "processing-auto-process",
                "value": "0",
                "valueType": "Boolean",
                "configurationTypeId": 6,
                "definition": null,
                "isDefault": false
              },
              {
                "id": 1074,
                "icon": "subdirectory_arrow_right",
                "title": "Allow Under Picking",
                "description": "Allow under pick when processing order?",
                "code": "processing-allow-under-picks",
                "value": "0",
                "valueType": "Boolean",
                "configurationTypeId": 6,
                "definition": null,
                "isDefault": false
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

**2. object desired:**

```
 [
      {
        "id": 17,
        "code": "daily-order-cut-off-time",
        "value": "09:35"
      },
      {
        "id": 1078,
        "code": "processing-auto-process",
        "value": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": 1074,
        "code": "processing-allow-under-picks",
        "value": "0"
      }
    ]
```

**My slow solution:**

```
const result = data.map(module => module.groups.map(configurations => configurations.configurations.map(config => ({ id: config.id, code: config.code, value: config.value })))).reduce((l,n) => l.concat(n), []).reduce((l2,n2) => l2.concat(n2),[]));
```

Comment: Is the ES6 spread operator available to you?  `result = [].concat(...[].concat(...data.map( d => d.groups.map( g => g.configurations.map( c => ({id:c.id, code:c.code, value:c.value}))))))`

Comment: yes it is available.

Comment: AMAZING! YOUR CODE IS BEAUTIFUL!, please answer my question I will mark as the correct answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, the ES6 spread operator flattens like you want.  The syntax is a little weird for multiple invocations:

```
result = [].concat(...[].concat(...data.map( d => d.groups.map( g => g.configurations.map( c => ({id:c.id, code:c.code, value:c.value}))))))
```

The `arr.flat()` method does the same thing more simply.  It takes an optional *depth* argument to indicate how many levels to descend when flattening.  In your case, depth is 2.

`.flat` is a recent feature that [may not exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility) on your platform.  Most notably, Node 10 and MS Edge do not have it, while both of those do have the spread operator:

```
data.map( d => d.groups.map( g => g.configurations.map( c => ({id:c.id, code:c.code, value:c.value})))).flat(2)
```

Comment: also, the use of the command .flat() would help somehow in this solution? thanks.

Comment: yes, if you have it.  See my edit.